# Issue with activity stack. Why and how it happens?

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image]

So here is the flow of my app....I guess the flow is very clear from this diagram so I am shifting directly to my point

The notification can recreate the player activity even if it is destroyed...

the playing screen starts a foreground service...

So here is where I am stuck...
suppose I start the player activity from fragment b, now I press back, the player activity gets destroyed (after starting the service and the notification)...now I press back again, the fragments are destroyed now...

Now I recreate the player activity again from the notification, but pressing back again will not take me back to the fragments as they were destroyed already...I want it to take me back to the fragments again (only if activity a and activity b didn't start it, in other words activity a and activity b are not in the back stack)? how can I achieve it?

I can think of a solution where I can override onbackpressed and start the activity again with proper checks on which activity started it and if that activity was already destroyed or not ...and for checks I thought of global variables, but this seems like a lame work around, is there any way by using activity stack etc, by which I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {

         moveTaskToBack (true);
     }
```

## Edit :i used the above code in the activity which holds the fragments

this did the work,damn i am so stupid ,i didn't even try before starting the bounty 
anyways i think it might be helpful to others,also this question and answer shows a   proper usage of moveTaskToBack .But I  don't know who to give the bounty to lol......

Comment: If you find the answer for yourself, post it, and accepts it, the bounty will be forfeit. No one will be rewarded and your rep will be lost.

Comment: yeah i know my repo will be lost lol ...it is better to give it away i guess

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a parentActivityName to synthesize a back stack. Read more here -http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent

Comment: well i already solved it,with one line of code ..... but i was giving the bounty to some one with the detailed explanation